# Extract numbers from string and store them in array-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following string

```
var string ="border-radius:10px 20px 30px 40px";
```

I want to take those 4 values(10,20,30,40) and store them in an array.
To do that i wrote the following code:

```
var numbers=string.split('border-radius:');
numbers=numbers[1];
numbers=numbers.split("px");
```

My code is working five i get the output i want.My question is:Is there a cleaner code or a better code to achieve the same result?
Here is my output:

```
["10", " 20", " 30", " 40", ""]
```

Comment: Use regex to extract the numbers

Comment: If that works for you, using `split` is probably the easiest and most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324633/find-and-get-only-number-in-string

Comment: I am new to programming and i have no idea about regex

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.match` with `Regexp`

```js
var string = "border-radius:10px 20px 30px 40px";
var result = string.match(/\d+/g);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var string ="border-radius:10px 20px 30px 40px";
var array = string.match(/[0-9]+/g);
alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```